# Paring groups for random event

Tags: probability

There are N group for a race event and each group must be opponent all of the groups except itself.

What is the best way to do this?

(I couldn't decide which tag for the best so you can answer in generally.)

Comment: What have you tried? Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: There is no *best way* to do this. You have to define what best means.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if by the best way you mean you want to minimize the number of matches/rounds, then there must be atleast as many matches as the number of ways of choosing $2$ out of $N$ groups, i.e. $${N\choose 2}=\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$$